# Экранирование и регулярные выражения. PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, экранирование

Задание: Если переменная `$text` не содержит специальных символов - вывести соответствующее сообщение . Никак не получается заставить программу учитывать обратный слэш, хоть с экранированием, хоть без:

```
$pattern = '/[~!@#$%^&*()+`\'";:<>\/\\|]/';
$text = 'ab\c';
if (!(preg_match($pattern, $text))){
    echo "Great! Special symbols was not found!";    }
```

В данном случае - программа все равно выводит заданное сообщение

Comment: у вас в условии пара лишних скобок, и похоже что оператор `!` тут не нужно использовать.

Comment: Да нет, с этим все в порядке, а скобки для того, чтобы мне было удобнее понимать код

Comment: ну тогда попробуйте добавть перед слешами ещё один (третий) экранирующий слеш. я не за пк, поэтому запустить и проверить код не имею возможности

Comment: Ура, сработало! Только я не могу понять, почему

Comment: я не помню, с чем это связано - в книге по регулярным выражениям сможете об этом почитать. Может быть это потому, что вы экранируете внутри символьного класса.

Comment: а не проще проверять на нормальные символы?

Comment: В обычных строковых литералах (с двойными и одиночными кавычками) надо использовать двойной знак обратной косой черты для обозначения символа ``\``. Так как для экранирования метасимволов регулярок нужны два таких символа, нужно использовать 4 ``\``: ``$pattern = '/[~!@#$%^&*()+`\'";:<>\/\\\\|]/';``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew почему бы не написать ответ вместо комментария?

Answer (score 2):

В строковых литералах с двойными и одиночными кавычками, а также Heredoc, надо использовать двойной знак обратной косой черты для обозначения символа `\`. Так как для экранирования метасимволов регулярных выражений нужны два таких символа, нужно использовать четыре знака `\`:

```
$pattern = '/[~!@#$%^&*()+`\'";:<>\/\\\\|]/';
                                    ^^^^
```

См. [раздел Строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) (*"Одинарные кавычки"*):

> Если необходимо написать сам обратный слеш, продублируйте его (`\\`)

Далее [в разделе "Двойные кавычки"](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) написано

> `\\`    обратная косая черта

Если же объявить шаблон в [строковом литерале типа Nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc), дополнительного экранирования `\` можно избежать:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOT'
/[~!@#$%^&*()+`'";:<>\/\\|]/
EOT;

$text = 'ab\c';
echo "$text\n";
if (!(preg_match($pattern, $text))){
    echo "Great! Special symbols was not found!";    
}
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/biYLy2).

Answer (score 0):

Вариант имеется без запары с экранированием (ну только одну \' в данном случае). Скорость с регуляркой не сравнивал

```
$pattern = '[~!@#$%^&*()+`\'";:<>/\|]';
$text = 'ab\c';
if ( str_replace(str_split($pattern), '', $text)==$text ){
    echo "Great! Special symbols was not found!";    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если запрещенные символы только однобайтовые - все проще:

```
$bad_chars = '[~!@#$%^&*()+`\'";:<>/\\|]';
$text = 'ab\\c';
if (($bad_start = strpbrk($text, $bad_chars)) === false) {
    echo "Great! Special symbols was not found!";
} else {
    echo "Error! Found special symbol `{$bad_start[0]}`";
}
```