# Почему регулярное выражение "~[^\\\]=~" так работает в PHP?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно составить регулярное выражение для поиска знака равно, перед которым стоит любой символ, кроме `\`. Вот такое `'~[^\\\]=~'` работает, а `'~[^\\]=~'` - ошибка компиляции "missing terminating ] for character class". Почему нужно `\\\`, а не `\\`? Ведь по сути мне нужно просто экранировать `\`, что я и делаю с помощью `\\`. Зачем еще один бэкслэш? И почему все-таки ошибка компиляции происходит?
Спасибо за разъяснение заранее

Comment: Вам надо удвоить символы обратной косой черты, ``'~[^\\\\]=~'``. См. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/913193/182013).

Comment: Если кстати вам только сами знаки равно надо найти, то лучше негативный просмотр назад использовать.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php абзац про `\\` выделен отдельно.

Comment: Да, но почему работают три слэша?

Comment: Оно работает потому что вы экранируете \, а потом ].

Comment: В смысле: я экранирую `"\\"`, получаю в строке символ `"\"`, затем экранирую  `"\]"`, получаю в строке `"]"`, в итоге в самой строке у меня содержится `"~[^\]=~"`? А в случае с `"~[^\\\\]=~"` получается, что в самой строке содержится `"~[^\\]=~"` и по смыслу это эквивалентно `"~[^\]=~"`? Хорошо, тогда в `"~[^\\]=~"`  я экранирую `"\\"`, получаю в самой строке `"~[^\]=~"` - почему ошибка компиляции тогда? Не могу понять логику

Comment: Кажется, понял, '"~[^\\\]=~"' здесь `"\\"` дает в строке символ `"\"`, `"\["` - дает в строке два символа `"\"``"["`, поскольку экранирования не происходит, в итоге получается строка '"~[^\\]=~"', в которой `"\\"` интерпретируется регулярными выражениями как `"\"`.

Comment: Кажется, понял,`"~[^\\\]=~"` здесь `"\\"` дает в строке символ `"\"`, `"\["` - дает в строке два символа `"\"` `"["`, поскольку экранирования не происходит, в итоге получается строка `"~[^\\]=~"`, в которой `"\\"` интерпретируется регулярными выражениями как `"\"`.
В `'~[^\\\\]=~'` четыре слэша переходят в строку в два слэша, которые интерпретируются регулярными выражениями как один слэш.
А вот в случае `"~[^\\]=~"` два слэша переходят в строку как один слэш и теперь в строке  имеем `"\]"`, и регулярные выражения интерпретируют его как обычный символ `"]"`, а не как закрытие класса!